# Android delete file from /data/data

Tags: android

I'm doing some tests between two apps I've created.

I want from one app, lets say, app `A`, delete a file that is from app `B`.

From within app `A` I can have access to `/data/data/com.app.A/files/` and delete all files in that directory. The problem is that I want from app `A`, delete files in `/data/data/com.app.B/files/`.

I understand that this is a security risk but as I said before I'm doing some tests with my apps and this is only to perform on my rooted phone.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible if the owning app grants everyone write and execute access to the parent *directory*, or changes the ownership of the *directory* to the other app's user ID, or they have a shared user ID, or you use an "su" root shim to launch a standalone file-deletion tool (typically "rm") as the superuser.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks, I know I can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` to get `su` but after that how could I use that to delete a file?

Comment: Use it to launch `rm` depending on what your particular hacked `su` supports. There are *many* questions on that topic here.  There's also some library people use called root tools or something like that.  Please try to resolve your issue using the resources already posted here.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I figure it out :)